# python: get variable name passed as argument to a function

Tags: python, namespaces, parameter-passing

I would like to retrieve the variable name passed as an argument to a function.

Here is an example of the result I am looking for:

```
def my_func(a, b):   
    return a + b

>>> foo, bar = 1, 2
>>> get_arg_var_names(my_func(foo, bar))
foo
bar
```

Please note that I am not looking retrieve `a` and `b`.

Comment: What if the function gets called like `my_func(1,2)`? What if it gets called like `my_func(input(), input())`? What if it gets called like `t = (23, 42); my_func(*t)`?

Comment: What is the purpose of using the names of the variables which were passed in? Aren't the variable names declared inside the function good enough to access the values?